# Confused over Bootstrap css grid, flex and row layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-grid

I have lately used CSS grid for my layouts, but I am now on a project that still needs to support `IE11`.

As CSS grid just does not seem to have much support, and as the project already uses `Bootstrap` css, I am trying to do what I thought would be a simple layout using it.

The layout I am trying to copy using Bootstrap, as would be done using `css grid`, can be seen on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/afxy8j47/9/)

So we have a simple two row layout, with a footer row

```
 //html
 <div class='container'>    
        <div class='item1'>
                aaaaaaaa
        </div>
        
        <div class='item2'>
            bbbbbbbbbb        
        </div>
 </div>


//css
html, body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
}

.container {
        min-height: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 50px;
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

.item1 {    
        background: pink;
        color: #444;
}

.item2 {    
        background: yellow;
 }
```

So we get..

[image]

I am now trying to do the same thing using `Bootstrap` so it will work in `IE`.

My first confusion, there seems to be a [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/) and a [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), so I am not sure which to use, and why there are two systems.

I have tries each, and I just cannot get the same thing to work.

Using the grid, it says to have a `container`, and then add `rows` (lets not worry about columns)

So I added

```
    <div class='cc container'>    
        <div class="item1 row align-items-stretch">
                aaaaaaaa
        </div>
        
        <div class="item2 row align-items-end">
            bbbbbbbbbb        
        </div>
 </div>
 
 
 html, body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
}

.cc {
    height: 100vh;
    background: blue;
}
.item1 {
        background: pink;    
}

.item2 {    
        background: yellow;
 }
```

Also can see this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/peterjc/afxy8j47/11/).

I just cannot get the footer to sit at the bottom. The `align-items-end` seems to do nothing.

I just see

[image]

I tried similar things with the `flex`, ie

```
<div class="d-flex align-self-end">Aligned flex item</div>
<div class="d-flex align-self-baseline">Aligned flex item</div>
```

but no luck here either.

I have spent hours, but I just can't get it to work (even in Chrome). All the doco seems to talk about is columns layout, but I need rows.

A minor question is why there is grid and flex, but my main question is should I be using the Bootstrap grid, flex, or a combination to try and get this "vertical" alignment, (is this possible)?

Comment: align-items, row etc. are Flex-properties, that means the Element you apply them to have to be Flex-elements. Thats why they dont do anything. So if you want to use align-items you have to use flex for the same element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the flex layout, give your `.item1` a `flex` value of 1

```
.item1 {
    flex: 1;
}
```

This will force that element to take up all of the remaining space and force the footer to the bottom.

Comment: Thank you @Dan. I now see the bootstrap classes do actually set (the real) flex styles underneath, perhaps looking after some prefixes for IE. So, from the Flex css the above `flex:1`, or `flex-grow:1` is what I needed, and this is obviously (as I tried it)  a style that works in IE